# Show div when hover over another separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched the web and found similar questions to my own, but I have not been able to achieve the results that I am looking for. I am not the most well versed with html/css/and javascript/jquery so I am wondering if it is an error on my part with how I am formatting everything, or the path to which I am trying to write these results.

I have three circles, spaced equally in the center of the page. Each circle links out to a different page. On hovering over a circle, a span is revealed (by changing the opacity property in css) that provides a title for where that link goes.

What I am having trouble doing is: When you hover over each circle, in addition to a span being revealed that provides a title, I want to have a short descriptive text appear below the circles. When you mouse out of that said circle, the descriptive text will disappear. Each circle must have its own descriptor text.

From what I have gathered, the jquery hover on event is likely the best way to do this, however I cannot seem to get the syntax correct to make it work.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#text1').hide();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.grid_1').hover(function() {
jQuery(this).find('#text1').show();
},
function() {
jQuery('#text1').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I should clarify anything.

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw6p1mL9/#&togetherjs=SndwMcpMce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery references `#text1` and it should be `.text1` since that element is a class. Also `$(this).find('.text').show();` won't work because `.text` is not a child of the thing you're hovering over (`$(this)`). Just use `$('.text1')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.text1').hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.grid_1').hover(function() {
      $('.text1').show();
    },
    function() {
      $('.text1').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.gridcontainer {
 width: 720px;
 margin: 30px auto;
}

.grid_1 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}
.grid_2 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}
.grid_3 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}


.fmcircle_out {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 opacity: 0.75; 
 
 border-radius: 100px;
 border: solid 2.5px #8D8B8B;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 -o-border-radius: 100px;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

 .fmcircle_out:hover {
  opacity: 1; 
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
 }

.fmcircle_in {
 width: 170px;
 height: 170px;
 margin: 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 
 border-radius: 85px;
 -moz-border-radius: 85px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 85px;
 -o-border-radius: 85px;
}

.fmcircle_in img {
 border: none;
 margin: 30px 25px 25px 25px;

  
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.fmcircle_in span {
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 width: 160px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #666666;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 70px 0 0 0;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 0.08em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 
 border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -o-border-radius: 2px;
  
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

 .fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in span {
  opacity: 1;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
 }
.fmcircle_out:focus {
 opacity: 1;
}
.fmcircle_blue {
 background-color: #35C317;
}

.fmcircle_red {
 background-color: #BA282B;
}

.fmcircle_green {
 background-color: #2E70DC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gridcontainer clearfix">
  <div class="grid_1">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link1.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_blue">
          <span>Link 1</span><img src="images/image location1" alt="image1" class="image1" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_2">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link2.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_green">
          <span>Link 2</span><img src="images/image location2" alt="image2" class="image2" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_3">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link3.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_red">
          <span>Link 3</span><img src="images/image location3" alt="image3" class="image3" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text_container">
  <p class="text1">Text box1</p>
  <p class="text2">Text box2</p>
  <p class="text3">text box3</p>
</div>
```

Though I would re-write it to be a little more flexible and with less code like this, utilizing a `data` attribute in the `.grid` circles to define the text block class to show, then adding/removing a class that shows the text instead of using jquery's `$.hide()` and `$.show()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.grid').hover(function() {
      $($(this).attr('data-text')).addClass('show');
    },
    function() {
      $($(this).attr('data-text')).removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
.gridcontainer {
 width: 720px;
 margin: 30px auto;
}

.grid_1 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}
.grid_2 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}
.grid_3 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}


.fmcircle_out {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 opacity: 0.75; 
 
 border-radius: 100px;
 border: solid 2.5px #8D8B8B;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 -o-border-radius: 100px;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

 .fmcircle_out:hover {
  opacity: 1; 
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
 }

.fmcircle_in {
 width: 170px;
 height: 170px;
 margin: 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 
 border-radius: 85px;
 -moz-border-radius: 85px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 85px;
 -o-border-radius: 85px;
}

.fmcircle_in img {
 border: none;
 margin: 30px 25px 25px 25px;

  
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.fmcircle_in span {
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 width: 160px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #666666;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 70px 0 0 0;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 0.08em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 
 border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -o-border-radius: 2px;
  
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

 .fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in span {
  opacity: 1;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
 }
.fmcircle_out:focus {
 opacity: 1;
}
.fmcircle_blue {
 background-color: #35C317;
}

.fmcircle_red {
 background-color: #BA282B;
}

.fmcircle_green {
 background-color: #2E70DC;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gridcontainer clearfix">
  <div class="grid_1 grid" data-text=".text1">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link1.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_blue">
          <span>Link 1</span><img src="images/image location1" alt="image1" class="image1" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_2 grid" data-text=".text2">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link2.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_green">
          <span>Link 2</span><img src="images/image location2" alt="image2" class="image2" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_3 grid" data-text=".text3">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link3.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_red">
          <span>Link 3</span><img src="images/image location3" alt="image3" class="image3" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text_container">
  <p class="text1 text">Text box1</p>
  <p class="text2 text">Text box2</p>
  <p class="text3 text">text box3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This snippet generates an error for me, `$` is not defined.  Maybe it was supposed to include JQuery?

Comment: @DanFarrell oops! I did! Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, that removed the error, but now I'm seeing `Text box2` and `text box3` regardless of mouse position, thoiught `Text box1` is seeming to work.  Edit: I guess that was intended.

Comment: @DanFarrell that's all the code OP has in their fiddle (hiding/showing the 1st text box). Just to show them why their jQuery wasn't working. They can extend that same logic to apply to their other boxes. I didn't want to do that, their approach isn't very efficient. But I finished their project for them with a second answer.

Comment: Wow, can't believe how fast this got responses. @MichaelCoker, thank you, this solved my question! Not sure I follow your second answer, when I run the snippet I get an error.

Comment: @k0ok no problem. Try the second answer again. I forgot to include the jquery library in the answer.... again... :)

Comment: Ok, that works! Is there a way to add an ease in factor to the jquery?

Comment: @k0ok describe what your end goal is. ease in what? You mean you want to fade the text instead of hide/show?

Comment: Still hide show the text, but on hover event of the circle have a transition of 0.2s (or something similar) to ease the text in and out

Comment: @k0ok look at CSS `transition`, `animation`, and jQuery's `$.fadeIn()`, `$.fadeOut()`, and `$.fadeTo()`. If you can't figure it out, post a new question with what you tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a css solution since there exist a jquery answer

Add the following to your css

```
.fmcircle_out:hover .description{
    opacity:1;
  }
  .description{
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 1s;
  }
  .fmcircle_out a{
    text-decoration:none;
  }
.fmcircle_out:focus {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

See snippet (Note you can add these rules to existing rules declared if you'd like)

```css
.gridcontainer {
  width: 720px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.grid_1 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}

.grid_2 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}

.grid_3 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}

.fmcircle_out {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid 2.5px #8D8B8B;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.fmcircle_out:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.fmcircle_in {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 85px;
  -moz-border-radius: 85px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 85px;
  -o-border-radius: 85px;
}

.fmcircle_in img {
  border: none;
  margin: 30px 25px 25px 25px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.fmcircle_in span {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 160px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666666;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 70px 0 0 0;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.fmcircle_out:hover .description {
  opacity: 1;
}

.description {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.fmcircle_out a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fmcircle_out:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fmcircle_blue {
  background-color: #35C317;
}

.fmcircle_red {
  background-color: #BA282B;
}

.fmcircle_green {
  background-color: #2E70DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridcontainer clearfix">
  <div class="grid_1">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link1.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_blue">
          <span>Link 1</span><img src="images/image location1" alt="image1" class="image1" />
        </div>
        <div class="description">This link describes option 1</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_2">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link2.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_green">
          <span>Link 2</span><img src="images/image location2" alt="image2" class="image2" />
        </div>
        <div class="description">This link describes option 2</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_3">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
      <a href="link3.html">
        <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_red">
          <span>Link 3</span><img src="images/image location3" alt="image3" class="image3" />
        </div>
        <div class="description">This link describes option 3</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text_container">
  <p class="text1">Text box1</p>
  <p class="text2">Text box2</p>
  <p class="text3">text box3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery code Which hide another div on hover and make it visible when mouse move out.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.grid_1').hover(     
   function () {
  $('#text1').hide();
 }, 

 function () {
   $('#text1').show();
  }
   );
  });
```